# Multiplication Table for Contiguous Numbers Python

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, formatting, multiple-columns

The output should look like [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mplgj.png). It is a multiplication table of 9 rows times 12 columns (technically 13).

The first column is 10 characters wide and is left aligned. All other columns are five characters wide and are right-aligned.

This is my code so far but I'm trying to format the multiplication table to be in the same rows as everything else

**I am not allowed to use any external modules such as itertools or functools**

```
 print(f"{'Column':<10s}", end = '\t'),
    for x in range(1,13):
        print(f"{x:5}", end='')


print(f"{'Column':<10s}", end = '\t'),
for x in range(1,13):
    print(f"{x:>5}", end='')

print() 
for x in range(1,10):
    print('Row',f'{x:<10}')


for row in range (1, 10):
    for col in range(1,13):
        print(f'{row*col:>5}', end="\t")
```

This is what I get:

```
Column          1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
Row 1         
Row 2         
Row 3         
Row 4         
Row 5         
Row 6         
Row 7         
Row 8         
Row 9         
    1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10      11      12       2       4       6       8      10      12      14      16      18      20      22      24       3       6       9      12      15      18      21      24      27      30      33      36       4       8      12      16      20      24      28      32      36      40      44      48       5      10      15      20      25      30      35      40      45      50      55      60       6      12      18      24      30      36      42      48      54      60      66      72       7      14      21      28      35      42      49      56      63      70      77      84       8      16      24      32      40      48      56      64      72      80      88      96       9      18      27      36      45      54      63      72      81      90      99     108
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cycle on cols should be nested inside the one in rows

```
for x in range(1,10):
    print('Row',f'{x:<10}', end="\t")
    for col in range(1,13):
        print(f'{row*col:>5}', end="\t")
```

Better do this:

```
for row in range(1,10):
    print('Row',f'{row:<10}', end="\t")
    print(*[str(row*col) for col in range(1,13)], sep = "\t", end="\n")
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the * do?

Comment: in a sense the * converts a list in a sequence of parameters and viceversa. It's a quite standard feature of the language and allows you to manage a variable number of named and unnamed parameters for instance in `print(*largs, **dargs)`.

Answer (score 0):

For @jumifiki's answer, if you don't understand the `*` in front of the list (which I don't either, actually), you can use the `join` method:

```
for row in range(1,10):
    print('Row',f'{row:<10}', end="\t\t")
    print('\t\t'.join([str(row*col) for col in range(1,13)]), end="\n")
```

Also, to make it even smaller you could use this:

```
for row in range(1,10):
    print(f'Row {row:<10} \t\t', '\t\t'.join([str(row*col) for col in range(1,13)]), end="\n")
```

You could even do a one-liner!!!

```
print('\n'.join([f'Row {row:<10} \t\t ' + '\t\t'.join([str(row*col) for col in range(1,13)]) for row in range(1, 10)]))
```

**NOTE:** At the top of the output, since there is supposed to be a `Column`, you could use this for that part:

```
print(f"{'Column':<12} ", end='\t\t ') # Use <12 becuse we have 2 more characters than each row label.
for c in range(1, 13):
    print(c, end="\t\t")
print()
```

Or, a one-liner:

```
print(f"{'Column':<12} \t\t", '\t\t'.join(map(str, range(1, 13))))
```

If you want, you can combine both of these print statements into ONE print statement so the whole thing is printed by ONE LINE!! (this is kinda crazy)

```
print(f"{'Column':<12} \t\t", '\t\t'.join(map(str, range(1, 13))) + '\n' + '\n'.join([f'Row {row:<10} \t\t ' + '\t\t'.join([str(row*col) for col in range(1,13)]) for row in range(1, 10)]))
```

(I suggest you don't use this, just for code readability)

Hope this helped you!

Comment: Thank you so much! what does \t\t do?

Comment: `\t\t` makes two tabs - `\t` makes one (I used these as you used them in your own answer as well). Also, if this answers your question, please accept it!